# Is the earth crust under the pacific ocean heavier than in the rest of the planet?

Tags: plate-tectonics, crust, oceanic-crust

Please bear with me, since I don't know much about geography or geology.

I was looking at an earth globe and noticed the pacific ocean covers virtually half of the planet (more or less). How is it even possible that this half is under water?

Is it because the crust under the pacific ocean is heavier than the rest of the world? Otherwise I can't understand why it's sunk so much. Does this make sense?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_tectonics, "Key principles", 3rd paragraph. I believe that answers your question?

Comment: Keep in mind, the Pacific is not deeper than other world oceans. In the grand scheme of plate tectonics depth is a function of age because of cooling, density increase, and a ductile layer that allows for subsidence.

Comment: There is less to this than meets the eye. Relative to its size, Earth's surface is as smooth as a billiard ball.